# How to synchronous useState with passing state to localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I ran into an asynchronous useState problem.

I have a situation where I first need to add an object to the state array in the handler. And then add this state to the localStorage.

```
setFavoritedSongs ((prev) => [...prev, {name: "Lala", length: "3:20"}]);

localStorage.setItem("storageItemName", JSON.stringify(favoritedSongs));
```

If I delete the entire localStorage first and run the handler. So an empty array is added to my localStorage (the state shows me updated). After the action again, the required object is finally added to my array.

I tried something like this, but still the same problem.

```
const tempArray = favoritedSongs.push({ name: "Lala", length: "3:20" });

localStorage.setItem(storageItemName, JSON.stringify(tempArray));
```

How do you solve this, please?

/// EDIT

I have something like this

```js
const FavoriteSong = () => {
  const song = { id: 1, name: "Lala", length: "3:20" };
  const [favoritedSongs, setFavoritedSongs] = useState([]);
  const [isFavorited, setIsFavorited] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("storageItemName")) {
      const storageSongs = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem("storageItemName") || ""
      );
      setFavoritedSongs(storageSongs);

      const foundSong = storageSongs?.find((song) => song.id === song.id);

      foundSong ? setIsFavorited(true) : setIsFavorited(false);
    }
  }, [song]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (isFavorited) {
      const filteredSong = favoritedSongs.filter(
        (song) => song.id !== song.id
      );
      localStorage.setItem("storageItemName", JSON.stringify(filteredSong));

      setIsFavorited(false);
    } else {
      setFavoritedSongs((prev) => [...prev, song]);

      localStorage.setItem("storageItemName", JSON.stringify(favoritedSongs));
      setIsFavorited(true);
    }
  };

  return <div onClick={handleClick}>CLICK</div>;
};

export default FavoriteSong;
```

Comment: Can you list the full code of your component? I have a few guesses, but I can't be sure as I don't see the full map.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can Use the **condition** If data in the array then It will set in localStorage otherwise not

```
const tempArray = favoritedSongs.push({ name: "Lala", length: "3:20" });

tempArray.length && localStorage.setItem(storageItemName, JSON.stringify(tempArray));
```

.

```
setFavoritedSongs ((prev) => [...prev, {name: "Lala", length: "3:20"}]);

FavoritedSongs.length(your state name) && localStorage.setItem("storageItemName", JSON.stringify(favoritedSongs));
```

Comment: Does not work. For example, when I'm trying to do something like this: `console.log(favoritedSongs.push(currentMovie))` It doesn't return an array of objects, just a number.

Comment: Actually whenever we do it like ..console.log(favoritedSongs.push(currentMovie))
It will return only a number because it returns that index where your new data push.
if you want favoritedSongs just write console.log(favoritedSongs).
I hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

Just place your `localStorage.set` logic inside a `useEffect` to make sure it runs after the state actually changes.

```
useEffect() => {
    localStorage.setItem(...);
}, [favoritedSongs]};
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible because there is another staff. See added code.